# Algorithm analysis: Choosing the best algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, inequality

I'm trying to solve a question about comparing 2 algorithms in terms of their worst case running times and finding the input size for which one algorithm would have a faster running time than the other.

The two algorithms are:
A<sub>1</sub> = 2n log<sub>10</sub> n
A<sub>2</sub> = 0.1n<sup>2</sup>

Basically, I am trying to solve the following inequality for n:
2n log<sub>10</sub> n < 0.1n<sup>2</sup>

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
I have managed to get up to:
log<sub>10</sub> n < 0.05n ==> n < 10<sup>0.05n</sup>

But I have no idea what to do from here (or perhaps I have gone about the wrong way trying to solve it).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Maybe more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Someone should point out that saying `2n log_10 n < 0.1n^2` is incorrect (the equation doesn't hold for `n=1`), you need to say `O(2n log_10 n) < O(0.1n^2)`, specify a value for `n`, or say 'asymptotically'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you are trying to solve the inequality

[image: point 1 n squared less than 2 times n log base 10 n]

because the [image: n squared] algorithm is only going to be faster for a very short time, and then for any larger values of n, the [image: n log n] algorithm will be faster.

Ignore the case n <= 0, multiply by 10, and divide by n to produce:

[image: n less than 20 log base 10 n]

Then divide by 20 and exponentiate both sides with a base of 10:

[image: 10 to the n over 20 less than n]

Use a numeric solver to find the zeros of [image: 10 to the n over 20 minus n] on the interval [1, 40] since clearly 40 is an upper bound (because [image: 10 to the 40 over 20 equals 10 squared equals 10,040]).

For instance, in Matlab:

```
>> fzero(@(x) 10^(x/20)- x, 20)

ans =

   29.3531
```

So for any n an integer up through 29, the [image: n squared] algorithm is faster, and for n > 29, the [image: n log n] algorithm wins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Can I just ask why 40 is clearly an upper bound?

Comment: I explained it in my answer, but someone edited it and caused a typo, and I don't know how to correct their typo. The typo is that it says 10040 instead of 100 is not less than 40. Look at the inequality and it is easy to understand: 10^(n/20) < n is true when n = 20, but false when n equals 40.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes much more sense now. But then wouldn't 30 be the upper bound, not 40? Because:
10^(30/20) = 31.6228 and 10^(29/20) = 28.1838
The final answer of 29 would still be correct, though.

Comment: @user2654949 Yes, the term "an upper bound" does not mean a single number. 30 is an upper bound and 40 is an upper bound. An upper bound is just any number where the inequality is false and above the values contained in the set of numbers where the inequality is true.

Comment: Yes, of course :) I guess I meant it as the least upper bound. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use sagemath to draw the image of function: plot(0.1 * n * n - 2 * n * log(n, 10), n, 0, 50)

[image]